# Debezium mongodb connector properties to limit cdc to specific collections

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-atlas, debezium, mongodb-kafka-connector

Can we **limit the amount of data we retrieve in connector properties in debezium mongodb** connector configurations.As debezium looks for cdc in database and according to my understanding it's for entire database and i couldn't find a way to limit few specific collections.
I am using mongodb atlas connection link in my debezium connector.

Below is my connector configs:

```
{
    "name": "inventory-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class" : "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
        "tasks.max" : "1",
        "mongodb.hosts" : "mongodb+srv link",
        "mongodb.name" : "database",
        "mongodb.user" : "user1",
        "mongodb.password" : "password",
        "mongodb.ssl.enabled" : true,
        "database.whitelist" : "db[.]*",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers" : "kafka:9092",
        "transforms": "route",
        "transforms.route.type" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
        "transforms.route.regex" : "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
        "transforms.route.replacement" : "$3"
    }
}
```

How to **configure it to look only for specific collections** in my database?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Debezium Connector for MongoDB documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/connectors/mongodb.html#connector-properties)
you can use `collection.whitelist` on the connector config to resolve your issue